# Strategy for converting a JS singleton to an instance/ctor

Tags: javascript, durandal

Below is a sample from the Durandal starter kit which is returning a singleton. I’m curious what the simplest way possible is to convert it to an instance, preferably without completely changing the syntax.

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'lodash'], function (http, app, ko, _) {
                var displayName = 'Flickr',
                                images = ko.observableArray([]),
                                activate = function () {
                                                //the router's activator calls this function and waits for it to complete before proceeding
                                                if (this.images().length > 0) {
                                                                return;
                                                }

                                                var that = this;
                                                return http.jsonp('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne', { tags: 'mount ranier', tagmode: 'any', format: 'json' }, 'jsoncallback').then(function(response) {
                                                                that.images(response.items);
                                                });
                                },
                                select = function(item) {
                                                //the app model allows easy display of modal dialogs by passing a view model
                                                //views are usually located by convention, but you an specify it as well with viewUrl
                                                item.viewUrl = 'views/detail';
                                                app.showDialog(item);
                                },
                                somePrivate = function() { return ‘blah’; },
                                canDeactivate = function () {
                                                //the router's activator calls this function to see if it can leave the screen
                                                return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
                                };

                return {
                                displayName: displayName,
                                images: images,
                                activate: activate,
                                select: select,
                                canDeactivate: canDeactivate
                };
});
```

This works but is a pain to add “this.” Everywhere and I also lose the public/private distinction from above:

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'lodash'], function (http, app, ko, _) {
                var ctor = function() {
                                this.displayName = 'Flickr';
                                this.images = ko.observableArray([]);
                                this.activate = function () {
                                                //the router's activator calls this function and waits for it to complete before proceeding
                                                if (this.images().length > 0) {
                                                                return;
                                                }

                                                var that = this;
                                                return http.jsonp('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne', { tags: 'mount ranier', tagmode: 'any', format: 'json' }, 'jsoncallback').then(function(response) {
                                                                that.images(response.items);
                                                });
                                };
                                this.select = function(item) {
                                                //the app model allows easy display of modal dialogs by passing a view model
                                                //views are usually located by convention, but you an specify it as well with viewUrl
                                                item.viewUrl = 'views/detail';
                                                app.showDialog(item);
                                };
                                this.canDeactivate = function () {
                                                //the router's activator calls this function to see if it can leave the screen
                                                return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
                                };
                };

    return ctor;
});
```

I would like something like the below to work– any tips?

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'lodash'], function (http, app, ko, _) {
    var ctor = function() {
        var displayName = 'Flickr',
            images = ko.observableArray([]),
            activate = function () {
                //the router's activator calls this function and waits for it to complete before proceeding
                if (this.images().length > 0) {
                    return;
                }

                var that = this;
                return http.jsonp('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne', { tags: 'mount ranier', tagmode: 'any', format: 'json' }, 'jsoncallback').then(function(response) {
                    that.images(response.items);
                });
            },
            select = function(item) {
                //the app model allows easy display of modal dialogs by passing a view model
                //views are usually located by convention, but you an specify it as well with viewUrl
                item.viewUrl = 'views/detail';
                app.showDialog(item);
            },
            canDeactivate = function () {
                //the router's activator calls this function to see if it can leave the screen
                return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
            };

        return {
            displayName: displayName,
            images: images,
            activate: activate,
            select: select,
            canDeactivate: canDeactivate
        };
    };

    return _.bind(ctor, this);
});
```

I also tried _.bindAll inside the ctor both before and after the vars.

Comment: sorry bro, you're going to have to get used to `this`

Comment: Ugh. Are you sure there isn't any trick using bind, extend or bindAll that can help keep the syntax similar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making ctor an IIFE? Like so:

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'lodash'], function (http, app, ko, _) {
var ctor = (function() {
    var displayName = 'Flickr',
        images = ko.observableArray([]),
        activate = function () {
            //the router's activator calls this function and waits for it to complete before proceeding
            if (this.images().length > 0) {
                return;
            }

            var that = this;
            return http.jsonp('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne', { tags: 'mount ranier', tagmode: 'any', format: 'json' }, 'jsoncallback').then(function(response) {
                that.images(response.items);
            });
        },
        select = function(item) {
            //the app model allows easy display of modal dialogs by passing a view model
            //views are usually located by convention, but you an specify it as well with viewUrl
            item.viewUrl = 'views/detail';
            app.showDialog(item);
        },
        canDeactivate = function () {
            //the router's activator calls this function to see if it can leave the screen
            return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
        };

    return {
        displayName: displayName,
        images: images,
        activate: activate,
        select: select,
        canDeactivate: canDeactivate
    };
}());

return ctor;
```

});

Comment: That is effectively the same thing as the singleton, i.e. the same instance is always used. I need a function to be returned so that each use of this gets a new instance. The solution I have works, I just hate that I have to completely redo the syntax and am looking for a nicer way.

Answer (score 0):

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'lodash'], function (http, app, ko, _) {
    var ctor = function() {
        var displayName = 'Flickr',
        images = ko.observableArray([]),
        activate = function () {
            //the router's activator calls this function and waits for it to complete before proceeding
            if (images().length > 0) {
                return;
            }

            var that = this;
            return http.jsonp('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne', { tags: 'mount ranier', tagmode: 'any', format: 'json' }, 'jsoncallback').then(function(response) {
                that.images(response.items);
            });
        },
        select = function(item) {
            //the app model allows easy display of modal dialogs by passing a view model
            //views are usually located by convention, but you an specify it as well with viewUrl
            item.viewUrl = 'views/detail';
            app.showDialog(item);
        },
        canDeactivate = function () {
            //the router's activator calls this function to see if it can leave the screen
            return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
        };

        _.extend(this, {
            displayName: displayName,
            images: images,
            activate: activate,
            select: select,
            canDeactivate: canDeactivate
        });
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

This seems to be pretty close to what I'm looking for and is an almost direct translation.